# Finding the cause of a corb job DefaultContentSourcePool error

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-corb

I'd been spending the day running corb scripts to test a simple script to read documents in my database, and suddenly my scripts are no longer able to connect to the database properly.  Corb reports this error:

> Jan 14, 2021 11:28:51 AM com.marklogic.developer.corb.DefaultContentSourcePool error
>
> WARNING: Connection error count for ContentSource user=redacted,
> cb=test [provider: address=localhost/127.0.0.1:9999, pool=1/64] is 1.
> Max limit is 3.
>
> Jan 14, 2021 11:28:51 AM
> com.marklogic.developer.corb.DefaultContentSourcePool$SessionInvocationHandler
> invoke
>
> WARNING: Submit request failed 1 times with ServerResponseException.
> Max Limit is 3. Retrying..
>
> Jan 14, 2021 11:28:51 AM
> com.marklogic.developer.corb.DefaultContentSourcePool get
>
> WARNING: Connection failed for ContentSource user=redacted, cb=test
> [provider: address=localhost/127.0.0.1:9999, pool=1/64]. Waiting for
> 60 seconds before retry attempt 2

Restarting MarkLogic (ML-10.0-5.1) hasn't helped.  Any ideas on what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, after looking at the port log for the corb server, I was trying to run a script that didn't exist.  a.k.a, I misspelled the file.